# In Swagger,for query-parameters when allowMultiple=true, how to send multiple values in comma seperated format?

Tags: java, csv, enums, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger-2.6.1, in a spring-mvc application.

For a query parameter, I need to allow multiple values. I have used `allowMultiple= true`. But this repeats the parameter name in the url for each value.

I need to send the parameter name once, with all the values in a comma-separated format.

How to do this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "testParam", value = "test parameter", dataType = "string", allowMultiple= true, allowableValues = "value1,value2,value3", paramType = "query"),
})
public String testMethod(){

    // code

}
```

**Existing url :** http://localhost:8080/testApi/test?testParam=value1&testParam=value2&testParam=value3
**Required url :** http://localhost:8080/testApi/test?testParam=value1,value2,value3

Comment: I have tried below code with swagger-2.8.0, but still no change :      
                           
 `@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "testParam", value = "test parameter", dataType = "string", allowMultiple= true, allowableValues = "value1,value2,value3", paramType = "query", collectionFormat = "csv"),
})`  
 Even after adding **collectionFormat = "csv"**, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following parameter to the annotation **@ApiImplicitParam**:

```
collectionFormat = "Set"
```

I used **@ApiParam** annotation and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is only one param  `testParam` with value  `value1,value2,value3`

What are you trying to do is to say swagger that there are more than 1 param when there is  only 1.

If you need multiple params use unique names for them like param1, param2, param3